# Azure to develop new web UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I want to develop a web UI for *azure*, what UI technology should I use as best practice? WPF ,ASP, Silverlight, MVC, other ?

In addition any sample/tutorial would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I feel HTML5 is the best way to go with server side using ASP.NET MVC.
Tutorials to start with

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2138.windows-azure-and-sql-database-tutorials.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2138.windows-azure-and-sql-database-tutorials.aspx (The automation script section might be of interest)
- http://www.asp.net/mvc (for asp.net mvc)

Hope this helps

Comment: And... this is why the question was closed. HTML5 is the best for *what*? There are dozens (hundreds?) of potential answers to this. There's simply no right answer. There are also non-.net languages such as node.js, along with Javascript / typescript, frameworks such as Backbone / Ember, etc...